# Rails simple_form associations with NoBrainer and RethinkDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form, rethinkdb, nobrainer

I am using simple_form as my form builder in a rails project, with RethinkDB as the database and the NoBrainer ORM. I have set up the models to include the relationships between them however when trying to generate the select dropdown for the association, I get the error **Association :currency not found**. Where am I going wrong?

```
class Country
    include NoBrainer::Document

    belongs_to :currency
    field :name, type: String
    field :nationality, type: String
end

class Currency
    include NoBrainer::Document

    has_many :countries
    field :name, type: String
    field :code, type: String
    field :symbol, type: String
end

= simple_form_for @country do |f|
    = f.input :name, placeholder: 'e.g. Namibia', label: 'Country'
    = f.input :nationality, placeholder: 'e.g. Namibian', label: 'Nationality'
    = f.association :currency, placeholder: 'Please select one', label: 'Currency', label_method: :code
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: So I see that NoBrainer does not yet support Reflection and this is why the f.association method does not yet work. There is a pull request however to include reflection support.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be doing anything wrong.

> Please note that the association helper is currently only tested with
>   Active Record. It currently does not work well with Mongoid and
>   depending on the ORM you're using your mileage may vary.
>
> https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

AFAIK your association is declared properly - but you may want to try specifying the collection to use for the options.

```
= f.association :currency, placeholder: 'Please select one', 
                label: 'Currency', 
                label_method: :code, 
                collection: Currency.all
```

If it still does not work you might want use [the lower-level collection input helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections) which is just some SimpleForm sugar on top of the Rails [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) method.

```
= f.input :currency_id, 
          label: 'Currency',
          collection: Currency.all,
          label_method: :code, 
          value_method: :id
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using HAML, you might need to adjust a bit if you are using Slim since the syntax for multi-line method calls is different.

Comment: Quite right. Seems to be simple_form not knowing how to handle associations with RethinkDB. Adding the collection makes no difference.

Comment: After much digging I found that the NoBrainer gem does not support reflection at this time although there is a pull request to include it (which does not yet work) so it should be available shortly.
And to answer your question, yes I can use a collection_select providing it with the collection needed. Hopefully the above gets sorted though because that will make life a whole lot easier.